# Open a specific directory and read all the text files

Tags: perl, cmd

Below codes is get into a folder`($directory)` search for text file and print out the `filename and size`. It is working fine if CMD path is `c:\modules\STP\New`, it able to read the `.txt` files in the specific folder. I guess it is working fine due to it matched the `$directory`. Unfortunately, when I run the codes on different path such as `c:\modules\STP`, it shows error. The error is `Can't call method "size" on a undefined value at line 12`. How can I fix this issue?

```
my $directory = 'c:\modules\STP\New';
my $file='filename.txt';
my $OUTFILE;

open $OUTFILE, '>>', $file;

my @files = do {
    opendir (my $dh, $directory);
    grep {/^.*\.txt\z/si} readdir($dh);
};
foreach(@files){
 my $filesize = stat($_)->size;   #<<<< LINE 12

  print { $OUTFILE } "$filesize $_" ,"\n";

}
```

Expected Result:

I expected the codes can be run in `c:\modules\STP` or any other CMD path. I doing this because I wish to reuse the code. Soon the `$directory` will not be hardcoded. Any solution or useful resource to share? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to include full path information when doing a file operation like [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).

The following is a cleanup of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::stat;

my $directory = 'c:\modules\STP\New';
my $file = 'filename.txt';

open my $outfh, '>>', $file;

opendir my $dh, "$directory";

while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
    next unless $file =~ /\.txt$/i;
    my $filesize = stat("$directory\\$file")->size;   # Include full path info
    print $outfh "$filesize $file\n";
}
```

#### Enhancement by using Path::Class

To ease the managing of full path and file info, I would recommend using a module like [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class).

The following does the same thing as your script, but ensures you aren't missing path information in your file test:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Path::Class;

my $dir = dir('c:\modules\STP\New');

open my $outfh, '>>', 'filename.txt';

while (my $file = $dir->next) {
    next unless $file =~ /\.txt$/i;
    printf $outfh "%s %s\n", $file->stat->size, $file->basename;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `glob()` which already gives full path to files, or add path using `map`,

```
my @files = do {
  opendir (my $dh, $directory) or die $!;
  map { "$directory/$_" }
  grep { /^.*\.txt\z/si }
  readdir($dh);
};
```

Comment: when I print out, the result suppose to be `127 filename.txt` but now the result is `127 c:\modules\STP\New/filename.txt`. It's include the directory path. Can you fix it so that the result will be `127 filename.txt`?

Comment: @thor_that_new_in_programming another approach is to use `$directory` prefix when doing `stat()` on files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some CPAN modules, what allows you many additional easying functions, my favorite is [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

From the docs:

> This module provide a small, fast utility for working with file
>   paths. It is friendlier to use than File::Spec and provides easy
>   access to functions from several other core file handling modules.
>   It aims to be smaller and faster than many alternatives on CPAN
>   while helping people do many common things in consistent and less
>   error-prone ways.

Your code with Path::Tiny

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my $directory = $ARGV[0] // ".";        #use 1st argument or current dir as default
my $pattern = qr/\.txt$/i;              #define your pattern to match

$iter = path($directory)->iterator({ recurse => 0 });
                                     #change to 1, if want recursively search subdirs

while ( $path = $iter->() ) {
    next unless $path =~ $pattern;
    say "$path: ", $path->stat->size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @content;
my $basedir = $ARGV[0];

if ( ! $basedir ){ $basedir = '/home/iwts/scripts'; }

find( \&wanted, $basedir );
foreach my $file ( @content ) {
    my $cmd = `ls -lh $file | awk '{print \$9 "\t" \$5 }'`;
    print $cmd;
}

sub wanted() { if ( $_ =~ m|^.*\.txt| ) { push @content, $File::Find::name; return; } }
```